# execute jquery in order

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I have a form on which there are 2 different jquery executed on it. Problem is that I need the first one to be executed first and if it's successful to execute the second.

Basically there is a form with 2 elements, the first jquery validates the form, the second popups up a confirmation window with Yes or No action. No simply closes the popup, Yes has to submit the form.

What is happening now is that that popup comes first and when clicking it, it validates the form. I need the opposite since the confirmation box has to include the 2 elements from the form.

my submit button has id : smart-mod-eg1

any help would be greatly appreciated

thanks

My code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var $formValidate = $('#form-id').validate({
        // Rules for form validation
        rules: {
            amount: {
                required: true
            },
            address: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        // Messages for form validation
        messages: {
            amount: {
                required: 'Please enter an amount'
            },
            address: {
                required: 'Please enter receiving address'
            }
        },
        // Do not change code below
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            error.insertAfter(element.parent());
        }
    });

    /*
     * SmartAlerts
     */
    // With Callback
    $("#smart-mod-eg1").click(function(e) {
        $.SmartMessageBox({
            title: "Confirm!",
            content: $("#amountSending").val(),
            buttons: '[No][Yes]'
        }, function(ButtonPressed) {
            if (ButtonPressed === "Yes") {
                content: $("#form-id").submit();
            }
            if (ButtonPressed === "No") {
                $.smallBox({
                    title: "Callback function",
                    content: "<i class='fa fa-clock-o'></i> <i>You pressed No...</i>",
                    color: "#C46A69",
                    iconSmall: "fa fa-times fa-2x fadeInRight animated",
                    timeout: 4000
                });
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    })
})
```

Comment: It does not matter when `.validate()` "executes" as long as it happens after the page is fully loaded.  The `.validate()` method is only how the plugin is _initialized_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is not a separate click handler, you need to use the `submitHandler` option of the validator

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var $formValidate = $('#form-id').validate({
        // Rules for form validation
        rules: {
            amount: {
                required: true
            },
            address: {
                required: true
            }
        },

        // Messages for form validation
        messages: {
            amount: {
                required: 'Please enter an amount'
            },
            address: {
                required: 'Please enter receiving address'
            }
        },

        // Do not change code below
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            error.insertAfter(element.parent());
        },

        submitHandler: function () {
            $.SmartMessageBox({
                title: "Confirm!",
                content: $("#amountSending").val(),
                buttons: '[No][Yes]'
            }, function (ButtonPressed) {
                if (ButtonPressed === "Yes") {
                    $("#form-id")[0].submit();
                }
                if (ButtonPressed === "No") {
                    $.smallBox({
                        title: "Callback function",
                        content: "<i class='fa fa-clock-o'></i> <i>You pressed No...</i>",
                        color: "#C46A69",
                        iconSmall: "fa fa-times fa-2x fadeInRight animated",
                        timeout: 4000
                    });
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: Hey, thank you very much. Now it properly executes one after the error. Only problem is that only "No" is working showing the other cancelled popup. But clicking Yes, does nothing, the overlay with Yes|No choices just stays there.

Any insight?

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Also for this line content: $("#amountSending").val(), .... what's the correct syntax to mix static words with form content?

So it shows like: Sending "X" amount to "recipient" which X and recipient are both form objects